# Determine which DOM elements the current text selection contains

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I want to be able to find out which DOM elements are present in the text currently selected by the user in the browser.

document.getSelection() would get us the currently selected text. But how can we determine which DOM elements are contained in this text selection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.getSelection()` gives you a [Selection](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#selection-0) object. Use `selection.rangeCount` and `selection.getRangeAt()` to get a [Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) object representing which selection you want.

Now you can get the first and last nodes in the selection from `range.startContainer`/`startOffset` and `range.endContainer`/`endOffset`. You could then walk up and down the tree to pick up all the elements in between those two positions, eg. using the `getElementsBetweenTree()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514125/jquery-select-elements-between-two-elements-that-are-not-siblings/2515169#2515169).

Unfortunately, IE's [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) model is totally different to the W3 and HTML5 standard, and in general much worse. It does't give up the start and end positions nearly as easily, and not in any reliable way. All you get is `parentElement` to tell you the common ancestor, and from there you're limited to guessing where the range is based on creating a new Range and calling `moveToElementText` on it then `compareEndPoints` with the selection range. And if you need to know the exact text selection you're then guessing based on `moveStart`/`moveEnd`​ing the range and comparing, which isn't fun at all.

Comment: IERange (http://code.google.com/p/ierange/) does a good job of creating a DOM Range-like object from a TextRange. I use my own slightly modified versions of the algorithms from IERange in my projects.

Comment: Looks good. (The critical bit with finding boundaries is in `TextRangeUtils.convertToDOMRange`.) It won't be a complete replacement for Range as IE TextRanges don't respect range boundaries around the edges of elements in the way Range is supposed to, but it's probably good enough for the common case.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I'm not sure it's possible to do much better in general and it has worked well for everything I've used it for. Can you think of any situation in which distinguishing between a boundary being at the edge of an element and it being at the edge of its child is critical? (e.g. `|<div><em>Text</em></div>` versus `<div>|<em>Text</em></div>` versus `<div><em>|Text</em></div>`)

Comment: Yeah, it's about the best you can do I think. It was an issue for some of my rich-editor stuff especially with empty elements. Hoping for some belated joy from IE9 on Range!

Comment: WebKit has issues too: you can't place the caret inside an empty element or indeed at the start of any text node (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23189). I've ended up writing code to insert (and later remove) Unicode BOM characters into empty elements I want the user to be able to type inside, which is both an unspeakable hack and a pain to manage.