# How can I split an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, textrange

I try to split an HTML section according to the selection point. For example suppose I have :

```
<table>
 <tr><td> one </td></tr>
 <tr><td> two </td></tr>
 <tr><td> tree </td></tr>
</table>
```

Now if the user selects `two` with mouse and click on a split button, I should have :

```
<table>
 <tr><td> one </td></tr>
</table>
```

And

```
<table>
 <tr><td> two </td></tr>
 <tr><td> tree </td></tr>
</table>
```

It can occur on any other element too (`P`, `div`, ...), and on any nested element.

I tried the following C# code:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc =
webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
IHTMLBodyElement body = doc.body as IHTMLBodyElement;
if (doc.selection != null)
{        
     if (doc.selection.type == "Text")
     {
          range = doc.selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;                        
          range.moveEnd("textedit");
          // NOW range.htmlText gives me the second part, 
          // however I don't know how to extract it from the section 
          // and remain the first part
     }
 }
```

Now [range.htmlText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives me the second fragment completely (with the parent tags), however I don't know how to extract it from the section and leave the first fragment?! `execCommand("cut")` may do the job, however if selection spans on several table rows that trick doesn't work.

Or any other solution?

Comment: What you need to know is which *parent* element contains the selection. [Example code here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2529482/451480). It gets more complex continuing from there, because then you need to determine which parent elements to close and reopen.

Comment: Why are you doing this on the server?

Comment: @rism on server? I do it on a webBrowser Control in a c# application

Comment: Ok so to rephrase. Why cant you do this using jQuery for instance? Do you have control over the html?

Comment: @rism No I can't do it with JQuery, its a desktop windows application.

Comment: You wouldn't use a text range for that, you would use DOM methods. For example, clone the table, append the clone as a sibling to the other table, remove, remove the appropriate rows from both instances.

Comment: @Tomalak good point, however the range.htmlText gives me what I needed!